# Angular navigation tip

Tags: angular

I would need a suggestion about the implementation of angular navigation.

My routes look like this:

main/route1
main/route2/id -> fe. main/route2/123, main/route2/321, ...
main/route3/id -> fe. main/route3/123, main/route3/321, ...

The side nav on my app can navigate the user to main/route1, main/route2 or main/route3

A secondary component controls the id. It's a dropdown. if I select an item I use that id to redirect to main/route2/123 or main/route3/123, ...

The problem is that in the side navigation I click on main/route2 I should redirect to default id if none was selected before, so I structured my router link something like this.

```
[routerLink]="['/main/route2', id$ | async]" routerLinkActive="active"
```

This is working fine if I am only redirecting in the side nav, but if I redirect in the second component the active class is not assigned. Why is this so? Do you have any idea how would you implement such navigation in your app? Maybe the secondary router?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am totally understanding your problem, but is this the kind of code you are looking for in your component, to force the route navigation:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };
  }
```